# How to get the code from a `.dll` in C++ 

Tags: dll

I have a `.dll` and I need some code from it. How do I get the code from a `.dll`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by code you mean the textual instructions that were used to generate the machine code in the library, the best you can really do at this point is assembly language. Nearly any debugger will let you view the assembly.

If you meant the original high level language, your out of luck.

Comment: How out of luck depends slightly on whether or not the code was compiled with debug information left in.  CLR DLLs also tend to be a good deal easier to move through than regular ASM (with ILDASM).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can open it up in a hex editor, but there is no way to get the original source code from compiled output. This is the basis for the entire closed-source (proprietary) software industry.